# iOS Swift: Pushing two view controllers when app launched from push notification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

When a user launches the app from a push notification I present one view controller, then push another. My code to present the first VC is as follows

```
let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let homeNav: UIViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeNavController") as! UINavigationController
            let homePageTableVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: HomePageTableViewController.self)) as! HomePageTableViewController
            homePageTableVC.tipToPresent = tipDay
            homeNav.addChildViewController(homePageTableVC)
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = homeNav
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

The tipToPresent property is used by the homePageTableVC (in the viewDidLoad method) to then present the second VC, using this code:

```
if let tipDayToPresent = tipToPresent {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tipVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: TipViewController.self)) as! TipViewController
        tipVC.dayOfTip = tipDayToPresent
        tipToPresent = nil
        navigationController?.pushViewController(tipVC, animated: true)
    }
```

This works well, but when I press the back button to return to the homePageTableVC, the navigation bar is blank. The title image, menu button, and right bar button that normally show up are not visible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding the title programmatically to your code?

navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = "YourTitle"

My guess is that since you are setting your storyboard programmatically, if you set your title in interface builder, it won't have access to that title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try changing this

```
homeNav.addChildViewController(homePageTableVC)
```

to this

```
homeNav.setViewControllers([homePageTableVC], animated: false)
```

Answer (score 3):

Good if solution by @augie works. I would suggest you should not change navigation stack when you handle push notification deep link. It should behave same as it does in normal app launch. By that way you don't need to handle any edge case and no need to set up different window.

**Solution:** Whenever someone click on push notification dismiss all presented controller and popToRootViewController and then navigate to desired screen.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is how you are adding your table on the navigation controller. Instead of making it your navigation's root viewcontroller you are adding it as a child vc.

Changing your code like this should work:

```
let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
// Remove type UIViewController                
let homeNav = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeNavController") as! UINavigationController

let homePageTableVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: HomePageTableViewController.self)) as! HomePageTableViewController
                homePageTableVC.tipToPresent = tipDay

// Set controllers instead of adding child
homeNav.setViewControllers([homePageTableVC], animated: false)
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = homeNav
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```